# Report Lab Printing Values From Forms Rather Than Database

Tags: django, django-forms, reportlab, django-database

I have a website where users must complete a large questionnaire spread over four webpages (and four forms) and after completing the questionnaire reportlab generates a pdf of their answers.

Here is my working code

utils.py

```
def generate_pdf(request):
    # get user
    user = request.user

    # get users age
    born = request.user.personalinformation.dob
    age = user_utils.get_age(born)

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\pdf_templates\\enrolment_form_%s.pdf' %user.id)
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    enrolment_form = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]

    page_contents = [
    ("Name: %s %s" % (user.personalinformation.first_name, user.personalinformation.surname)),
    ("Gender: %s" % (user.personalinformation.gender)),
    ("Age: %s" % (age))
    ]

    for sections in page_contents:
        p = Paragraph(sections, style)
        enrolment_form.append(p)
        enrolment_form.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))

    doc.build(enrolment_form)
```

models.py

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    GENDERS = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
    dob = models.DateTimeField('Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)', null=True, default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

(I also have a form.py but dont think its worth including)

This works fine, except for fields like 'gender'. Because its getting the values its printing on the pdf from user.personalinformation from the database, instead of printing 'Gender: Male', its printing 'Gender: M'. While this example seems trivial, there are many more fields with key/value pairs and booleans which make no sense printed this way.

How could I print the values as they are displayed in the form and to the user, rather than printing the values saved in the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from [field.choices documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

> For each model field that has choices set, Django will add a method to
>   retrieve the human-readable name for the field’s current value. See
>   get_FOO_display() in the database API documentation.

So you'll have to use [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) function to get value as documented

```
user.personalinformation.get_gender_display()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was after